# how to merge css in IE9

Tags: css

I want to load all the css files separately only for IE 9 is there a way to tell Magento to do that?
is there a call I can write in the head file to call all the needed css files?
to clarify I want to put in a call like that that gets the css unmerged

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
```

Comment: that mean you does not want to css merge for IE9

Comment: yes exactly what i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to fulfill ***your requirement you need customization/rewrite  at class Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head*** ,magento ***did not have any function of  which accomplice the requirement***

As per as default magento behave `js/css files are rendered/merge by getCssJsHtml() on this cass.`

On this function basic of configuration value 
***Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('dev/css/merge_css_files')*** css files are `merge`.

the value is store in a variable `$shouldMergeCss = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('dev/css/merge_css_files');`

So let make `$shouldMergeCss` value false whenever `user agent is IE9`

```
// track Ie9 Browser then make merge css false; 
if(preg_match('/(?i)msie [9-9]/',Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpUserAgent())):
    $shouldMergeCss =false;
else:
    $shouldMergeCss = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('dev/css/merge_css_files');
endif;
```

Code:

***config.xml code:***

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <config>
> ....
>   <global>
>       <blocks>
>           <page>
>               <rewrite>
>                   <html_head>[ModuleNameSpace]_[Modulename]_Block_Page_Html_Head</html_head>
>               </rewrite>
>           </page>
>       </blocks>
>   </global>
>   .....
> </config>
> ```

**rewrite class**

> ```
> <?php
> class [ModuleNameSpace]_[Modulename]_Block_Page_Html_Head extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head{
>     public function getCssJsHtml()
>     {
>         // separate items by types
>         $lines  = array();
>         foreach ($this->_data['items'] as $item) {
>             if (!is_null($item['cond']) && !$this->getData($item['cond']) || !isset($item['name'])) {
>                 continue;
>             }
>             $if     = !empty($item['if']) ? $item['if'] : '';
>             $params = !empty($item['params']) ? $item['params'] : '';
>             switch ($item['type']) {
>                 case 'js':        // js/*.js
>                 case 'skin_js':   // skin/*/*.js
>                 case 'js_css':    // js/*.css
>                 case 'skin_css':  // skin/*/*.css
>                     $lines[$if][$item['type']][$params][$item['name']] = $item['name'];
>                     break;
>                 default:
>                     $this->_separateOtherHtmlHeadElements($lines, $if, $item['type'], $params, $item['name'], $item);
>                     break;
>             }
>         }
>
>         // prepare HTML
>
>
>       $shouldMergeJs = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('dev/js/merge_files');
>
>       // track Ie9 Browser then make merge css false; 
>        if(preg_match('/(?i)msie [8-8]/',Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpUserAgent())):
>       $shouldMergeCss =false;
>       else:
>       $shouldMergeCss = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('dev/css/merge_css_files');
>       endif;
>
>         $html   = '';
>         foreach ($lines as $if => $items) {
>             if (empty($items)) {
>                 continue;
>             }
>             if (!empty($if)) {
>                 // open !IE conditional using raw value
>                 if (strpos($if, "><!-->") !== false) {
>                     $html .= $if . "\n";
>                 } else {
>                     $html .= '<!--[if '.$if.']>' . "\n";
>                 }
>             }
>
>             // static and skin css
>             $html .= $this->_prepareStaticAndSkinElements('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%s"%s />'."\n",
>                 empty($items['js_css']) ? array() : $items['js_css'],
>                 empty($items['skin_css']) ? array() : $items['skin_css'],
>                 $shouldMergeCss ? array(Mage::getDesign(), 'getMergedCssUrl') : null
>             );
>
>             // static and skin javascripts
>             $html .= $this->_prepareStaticAndSkinElements('<script type="text/javascript" src="%s"%s></script>' . "\n",
>                 empty($items['js']) ? array() : $items['js'],
>                 empty($items['skin_js']) ? array() : $items['skin_js'],
>                 $shouldMergeJs ? array(Mage::getDesign(), 'getMergedJsUrl') : null
>             );
>
>             // other stuff
>             if (!empty($items['other'])) {
>                 $html .= $this->_prepareOtherHtmlHeadElements($items['other']) . "\n";
>             }
>
>             if (!empty($if)) {
>                 // close !IE conditional comments correctly
>                 if (strpos($if, "><!-->") !== false) {
>                     $html .= '<!--<![endif]-->' . "\n";
>                 } else {
>                     $html .= '<![endif]-->' . "\n";
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         return $html;
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: please check update..

Comment: You donot use <!--[if lt IE 10]>  before4<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>

Answer (score 0):

Copy the below code and create a file named **Head.php** and place it under **app\code\local\Mage\Page\Block\Html**

```
<?php
    class Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
    {
        /**
         * Initialize template
         *
         */
        protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->setTemplate('page/html/head.phtml');
        }

        /**
         * Add CSS file to HEAD entity
         *
         * @param string $name
         * @param string $params
         * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
         */
        public function addCss($name, $params = "")
        {
            $this->addItem('skin_css', $name, $params);
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Add JavaScript file to HEAD entity
         *
         * @param string $name
         * @param string $params
         * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
         */
        public function addJs($name, $params = "")
        {
            $this->addItem('js', $name, $params);
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Add CSS file for Internet Explorer only to HEAD entity
         *
         * @param string $name
         * @param string $params
         * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
         */
        public function addCssIe($name, $params = "")
        {
            $this->addItem('skin_css', $name, $params, 'IE');
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Add JavaScript file for Internet Explorer only to HEAD entity
         *
         * @param string $name
         * @param string $params
         * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
         */
        public function addJsIe($name, $params = "")
        {
            $this->addItem('js', $name, $params, 'IE');
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Add Link element to HEAD entity
         *
         * @param string $rel forward link types
         * @param string $href URI for linked resource
         * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
         */
        public function addLinkRel($rel, $href)
        {
            $this->addItem('link_rel', $href, 'rel="' . $rel . '"');
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Add HEAD Item
         *
         * Allowed types:
         *  - js
         *  - js_css
         *  - skin_js
         *  - skin_css
         *  - rss
         *
         * @param string $type
         * @param string $name
         * @param string $params
         * @param string $if
         * @param string $cond
         * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
         */
        public function addItem($type, $name, $params=null, $if=null, $cond=null)
        {
            if ($type==='skin_css' && empty($params)) {
                $params = 'media="all"';
            }
            $this->_data['items'][$type.'/'.$name] = array(
                'type'   => $type,
                'name'   => $name,
                'params' => $params,
                'if'     => $if,
                'cond'   => $cond,
           );
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Remove Item from HEAD entity
         *
         * @param string $type
         * @param string $name
         * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
         */
        public function removeItem($type, $name)
        {
            unset($this->_data['items'][$type.'/'.$name]);
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get HEAD HTML with CSS/JS/RSS definitions
         * (actually it also renders other elements, TODO: fix it up or rename this method)
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getCssJsHtml()
        {
            // separate items by types
            $lines  = array();
            foreach ($this->_data['items'] as $item) {
                if (!is_null($item['cond']) && !$this->getData($item['cond']) || !isset($item['name'])) {
                    continue;
                }
                $if     = !empty($item['if']) ? $item['if'] : '';
                $params = !empty($item['params']) ? $item['params'] : '';
                switch ($item['type']) {
                    case 'js':        // js/*.js
                    case 'skin_js':   // skin/*/*.js
                    case 'js_css':    // js/*.css
                    case 'skin_css':  // skin/*/*.css
                        $lines[$if][$item['type']][$params][$item['name']] = $item['name'];
                        break;
                    default:
                        $this->_separateOtherHtmlHeadElements($lines, $if, $item['type'], $params, $item['name'], $item);
                        break;
                }
            }

            // prepare HTML
            $shouldMergeJs = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('dev/js/merge_files');
            $shouldMergeCss = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('dev/css/merge_css_files');
            $html   = '';
            foreach ($lines as $if => $items) {
                if (empty($items)) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (!empty($if)) {
                    // open !IE conditional using raw value
                    if (strpos($if, "><!-->") !== false) {
                        $html .= $if . "\n";
                    } else {
                        $html .= '<!--[if '.$if.']>' . "\n";
                    }
                }

                // static and skin css
                if($this->browser() !="IE9.0"):
                    $html .= $this->_prepareStaticAndSkinElements('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%s"%s />'."\n",
                        empty($items['js_css']) ? array() : $items['js_css'],
                        empty($items['skin_css']) ? array() : $items['skin_css'],
                        $shouldMergeCss ? array(Mage::getDesign(), 'getMergedCssUrl') : null
                    );
                else:
                    $html .= $this->_prepareStaticAndSkinElements('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%s"%s />'."\n",
                        empty($items['js_css']) ? array() : $items['js_css'],
                        empty($items['skin_css']) ? array() : $items['skin_css']
                    );
                endif;

                // static and skin javascripts
                $html .= $this->_prepareStaticAndSkinElements('<script type="text/javascript" src="%s"%s></script>' . "\n",
                    empty($items['js']) ? array() : $items['js'],
                    empty($items['skin_js']) ? array() : $items['skin_js'],
                    $shouldMergeJs ? array(Mage::getDesign(), 'getMergedJsUrl') : null
                );

                // other stuff
                if (!empty($items['other'])) {
                    $html .= $this->_prepareOtherHtmlHeadElements($items['other']) . "\n";
                }

                if (!empty($if)) {
                    // close !IE conditional comments correctly
                    if (strpos($if, "><!-->") !== false) {
                        $html .= '<!--<![endif]-->' . "\n";
                    } else {
                        $html .= '<![endif]-->' . "\n";
                    }
                }
            }
            return $html;
        }

        /**
         * Merge static and skin files of the same format into 1 set of HEAD directives or even into 1 directive
         *
         * Will attempt to merge into 1 directive, if merging callback is provided. In this case it will generate
         * filenames, rather than render urls.
         * The merger callback is responsible for checking whether files exist, merging them and giving result URL
         *
         * @param string $format - HTML element format for sprintf('<element src="%s"%s />', $src, $params)
         * @param array $staticItems - array of relative names of static items to be grabbed from js/ folder
         * @param array $skinItems - array of relative names of skin items to be found in skins according to design config
         * @param callback $mergeCallback
         * @return string
         */
        protected function &_prepareStaticAndSkinElements($format, array $staticItems, array $skinItems,
                                                          $mergeCallback = null)
        {
            $designPackage = Mage::getDesign();
            $baseJsUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('js');
            $items = array();
            if ($mergeCallback && !is_callable($mergeCallback)) {
                $mergeCallback = null;
            }

            // get static files from the js folder, no need in lookups
            foreach ($staticItems as $params => $rows) {
                foreach ($rows as $name) {
                    $items[$params][] = $mergeCallback ? Mage::getBaseDir() . DS . 'js' . DS . $name : $baseJsUrl . $name;
                }
            }

            // lookup each file basing on current theme configuration
            foreach ($skinItems as $params => $rows) {
                foreach ($rows as $name) {
                    $items[$params][] = $mergeCallback ? $designPackage->getFilename($name, array('_type' => 'skin'))
                        : $designPackage->getSkinUrl($name, array());
                }
            }

            $html = '';
            foreach ($items as $params => $rows) {
                // attempt to merge
                $mergedUrl = false;
                if ($mergeCallback) {
                    $mergedUrl = call_user_func($mergeCallback, $rows);
                }
                // render elements
                $params = trim($params);
                $params = $params ? ' ' . $params : '';
                if ($mergedUrl) {
                    $html .= sprintf($format, $mergedUrl, $params);
                } else {
                    foreach ($rows as $src) {
                        $html .= sprintf($format, $src, $params);
                    }
                }
            }
            return $html;
        }

        /**
         * Classify HTML head item and queue it into "lines" array
         *
         * @see self::getCssJsHtml()
         * @param array &$lines
         * @param string $itemIf
         * @param string $itemType
         * @param string $itemParams
         * @param string $itemName
         * @param array $itemThe
         */
        protected function _separateOtherHtmlHeadElements(&$lines, $itemIf, $itemType, $itemParams, $itemName, $itemThe)
        {
            $params = $itemParams ? ' ' . $itemParams : '';
            $href   = $itemName;
            switch ($itemType) {
                case 'rss':
                    $lines[$itemIf]['other'][] = sprintf('<link href="%s"%s rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" />',
                        $href, $params
                    );
                    break;
                case 'link_rel':
                    $lines[$itemIf]['other'][] = sprintf('<link%s href="%s" />', $params, $href);
                    break;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Render arbitrary HTML head items
         *
         * @see self::getCssJsHtml()
         * @param array $items
         * @return string
         */
        protected function _prepareOtherHtmlHeadElements($items)
        {
            return implode("\n", $items);
        }

        /**
         * Retrieve Chunked Items
         *
         * @param array $items
         * @param string $prefix
         * @param int $maxLen
         * @return array
         */
        public function getChunkedItems($items, $prefix = '', $maxLen = 450)
        {
            $chunks = array();
            $chunk  = $prefix;
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                if (strlen($chunk.','.$item)>$maxLen) {
                    $chunks[] = $chunk;
                    $chunk = $prefix;
                }
                $chunk .= ','.$item;
            }
            $chunks[] = $chunk;
            return $chunks;
        }

        /**
         * Retrieve Content Type
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getContentType()
        {
            if (empty($this->_data['content_type'])) {
                $this->_data['content_type'] = $this->getMediaType().'; charset='.$this->getCharset();
            }
            return $this->_data['content_type'];
        }

        /**
         * Retrieve Media Type
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getMediaType()
        {
            if (empty($this->_data['media_type'])) {
                $this->_data['media_type'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/default_media_type');
            }
            return $this->_data['media_type'];
        }

        /**
         * Retrieve Charset
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getCharset()
        {
            if (empty($this->_data['charset'])) {
                $this->_data['charset'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/default_charset');
            }
            return $this->_data['charset'];
        }

        /**
         * Set title element text
         *
         * @param string $title
         * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
         */
        public function setTitle($title)
        {
            $this->_data['title'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/title_prefix') . ' ' . $title
                . ' ' . Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/title_suffix');
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Retrieve title element text (encoded)
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getTitle()
        {
            if (empty($this->_data['title'])) {
                $this->_data['title'] = $this->getDefaultTitle();
            }
            return htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode(trim($this->_data['title']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        }

        /**
         * Retrieve default title text
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getDefaultTitle()
        {
            return Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/default_title');
        }

        /**
         * Retrieve content for description tag
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getDescription()
        {
            if (empty($this->_data['description'])) {
                $this->_data['description'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/default_description');
            }
            return $this->_data['description'];
        }

        /**
         * Retrieve content for keyvords tag
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getKeywords()
        {
            if (empty($this->_data['keywords'])) {
                $this->_data['keywords'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/default_keywords');
            }
            return $this->_data['keywords'];
        }

        /**
         * Retrieve URL to robots file
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getRobots()
        {
            if (empty($this->_data['robots'])) {
                $this->_data['robots'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/default_robots');
            }
            return $this->_data['robots'];
        }

        /**
         * Get miscellanious scripts/styles to be included in head before head closing tag
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getIncludes()
        {
            if (empty($this->_data['includes'])) {
                $this->_data['includes'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/includes');
            }
            return $this->_data['includes'];
        }

        /**
         * Getter for path to Favicon
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getFaviconFile()
        {
            if (empty($this->_data['favicon_file'])) {
                $this->_data['favicon_file'] = $this->_getFaviconFile();
            }
            return $this->_data['favicon_file'];
        }

        /**
         * Retrieve path to Favicon
         *
         * @return string
         */
        protected function _getFaviconFile()
        {
            $folderName = Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Image_Favicon::UPLOAD_DIR;
            $storeConfig = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/shortcut_icon');
            $faviconFile = Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $folderName . '/' . $storeConfig;
            $absolutePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/' . $folderName . '/' . $storeConfig;

            if(!is_null($storeConfig) && $this->_isFile($absolutePath)) {
                $url = $faviconFile;
            } else {
                $url = $this->getSkinUrl('favicon.ico');
            }
            return $url;
        }

        /**
         * If DB file storage is on - find there, otherwise - just file_exists
         *
         * @param string $filename
         * @return bool
         */
        protected function _isFile($filename) {
            if (Mage::helper('core/file_storage_database')->checkDbUsage() && !is_file($filename)) {
                Mage::helper('core/file_storage_database')->saveFileToFilesystem($filename);
            }
            return is_file($filename);
        }

        public function browser() {
            $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
            $browsers = array(
                                'Chrome' => array('Google Chrome','Chrome/(.*)\s'),
                                'MSIE' => array('IE','MSIE\s([0-9\.]*)'),
                                'Firefox' => array('Firefox', 'Firefox/([0-9\.]*)'),
                                'Safari' => array('Safari', 'Version/([0-9\.]*)'),
                                'Opera' => array('Opera', 'Version/([0-9\.]*)')
                                ); 

            $browser_details = array();

                foreach ($browsers as $browser => $browser_info){
                    if (preg_match('@'.$browser.'@i', $user_agent)){
                        $browser_details['name'] = $browser_info[0];
                            preg_match('@'.$browser_info[1].'@i', $user_agent, $version);
                        $browser_details['version'] = $version[1];
                            break;
                    } else {
                        $browser_details['name'] = 'Unknown';
                        $browser_details['version'] = 'Unknown';
                    }
                }

            return $browser_details['name'].$browser_details['version'];
        }
    }
```

CSS files will not merge for IE9 browser.
Working for me. Try it at your end.

Comment: Please explain in detail what you did and where instead of posting the whole class. I would advice people not to just copy paste the code since you don't know what might be in there

Answer (score 0):

ok i added

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
<?php echo $this->getIeCssJsHtml() ?>
<![endif]-->
```

to head.phtml

and made a module
with block/Head.php:

```
class Company_IeFix_Block_Head extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
{
        public function getIeCssJsHtml()
    {
        // separate items by types
        $lines  = array();
        foreach ($this->_data['items'] as $item) {
            if (!is_null($item['cond']) && !$this->getData($item['cond']) || !isset($item['name'])) {
                continue;
            }
            $if     = !empty($item['if']) ? $item['if'] : '';
            $params = !empty($item['params']) ? $item['params'] : '';
            switch ($item['type']) {
                case 'js':        // js/*.js
                case 'skin_js':   // skin/*/*.js
                case 'js_css':    // js/*.css
                case 'skin_css':  // skin/*/*.css
                    $lines[$if][$item['type']][$params][$item['name']] = $item['name'];
                    break;
                default:
                    $this->_separateOtherHtmlHeadElements($lines, $if, $item['type'], $params, $item['name'], $item);
                    break;
            }
        }

        // prepare HTML
        $shouldMergeCss = false;
        $html   = '';
        foreach ($lines as $if => $items) {
            if (empty($items)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!empty($if)) {
                $html .= '<!--[if '.$if.']>'."\n";
            }

            // static and skin css
            $html .= $this->_prepareStaticAndSkinElements('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%s"%s />' . "\n",
                empty($items['js_css']) ? array() : $items['js_css'],
                empty($items['skin_css']) ? array() : $items['skin_css'],
                $shouldMergeCss ? array(Mage::getDesign(), 'getMergedCssUrl') : null
            );

            // static and skin javascripts


            // other stuff
            if (!empty($items['other'])) {
                $html .= $this->_prepareOtherHtmlHeadElements($items['other']) . "\n";
            }

            if (!empty($if)) {
                $html .= '<![endif]-->'."\n";
            }
        }
        return $html;
    }
}
and config
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_IeFix>
            <version>0.9</version>
        </Company_IeFix>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <iefix>
                <class>Company_IeFix_Block</class>
            </iefix>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                    <html_head>Company_IeFix_Block_Head</html_head>
                </rewrite>
            </page>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: This is basically what other users suggested you to do. Please accept one of their answers since they put a lot of effort into taking time to answer questions